# OpenShift and redirect in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, openshift

I have a Wordpress app deployed on OpenShift and a domain alias associated, i.e. www.example.org. Now I would like to add another alias, i.e. www.example2.org, and gracefully redirect all the request from www.example.org => www.example2.org.
I tried to do this via .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.org$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example2.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Whenever contact www.example.org it generates an infinite loop of redirects and I can not understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Openshift rewrites the redirect header, but you can prevent this by adding the port number to the URL. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29052939/1415644).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). And `example.org` is not an alias of `example2.org`. It's a brand new [A record](https://support.google.com/a/answer/48090#H). You can eventually redirect `www.example.org` via your domain registrar's dashboard or create `index.php` with `header('Location: http://www.example2.org');`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.org/$1 [R,QSA,L]
```

Comment: www.example2.com and www.example.com are two CNAMEs pointing to the same openShift application, and they are both defined as alias on the app. In other words I simply want to change the application domain with graceful redirect from the old domain to the new domain.

Comment: Oh, now I see.. but still if sb types just "examples.org" he gets nowhere since it's A record and you never have a static IP address of your OpenShift app.

Comment: #2
In my case I redirected (301) "example.org" to "example2.org" right away in the domain's administration. It seems to me as the only working solution.